# How to communicate PHP with PhantomJS for solving Captchas

Tags: phantomjs

The problem I'd like to solve is the following:

I need to manage an external web page through PHP, for example, login and then change the profile info on the external web after sending an ajax request on my own web.

For this, I'm calling PhantomJS from PHP to do those tasks, but before login to the external web I need to fill the captcha input. So, I'd like to send back the Captcha image to my web, write the correct code and send it back to the WebPage module of PhantomJS to login using that code.

In other words, I need a 'syncronous' program like this:

1) PHP -> Send a request to login and obtain the captcha image.

2) PhantomJS -> Open a WebPage instance and render the captcha code to an image.

3) PHP -> Get the captcha image, show it to an user and send a text input to PhantomJS.

4) PhantomJS -> Get the text code from PHP, fill the captcha input using 'page.evaluate' and login. Send to PHP some data ('Login successfull', 'Login failed', etc)

5) PHP -> Get the callback and send another task or data.

```
callback = 'Login successfull' --> Change profile picture or update user info.

callback = 'Login failed' --> Try to login again (like point 1)
```

Etc...

There are many things I don't know how to handle. For example:

1) How could I keep the WebPage module open and waiting for the text code of the captcha? If I close it, a new captcha code will appear next time, and I need a way to wait the code and get it. Do I need to start a server for this?

2)Get the captcha image from PHP isn't a problem (because of 'page.render'), but how I could send a text back to the WebPage instance of PhantomJS? I think is better to send data bidirectionally between both systems. Again, do I need a server?

I think I need a socket server in PhantomJS (how can this be done?). This server should have the WebPage instance that I need to keep open, but I'm not completely sure about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your scenarios is precisely the one that site owners are trying to prevent using captchas. If you can contact the owner of the site where the captcha is on you can request some sort of webservice to use and make the changes needed.

Comment: I've already tried to communicate with them, with no answers. I could try again, but I think I need to solve this because is possible that they will never reply.
Can captcha inputs be filled using the solution I wrote here? Isn't impossible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a project that gives PHP access to a browser. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS, Under the hood is an instance of PhantomJS.

The main issue is keeping a resource alive after initial execution. Here is how i propose you do it.

After downloading and setup you would simply use the following code:

Start of "Setup" session:

```
if (isset($_POST['sessionUID']) === false) {

    //set the execution timeout long enough to cover the entire process (setup and working time), it dictates when phantomJS shuts down automatically.
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

    //open the login page:
    $myUrl          = "http://www.example.com";
    $browserObj      = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getBrowser('phantomjs');

    //allow the page to live after php shuts down.
    $browserObj->setKeepalive(true);
    $windowObj      = $browserObj->getNewWindow($myUrl);

    //find the username input box, here it has id=username
    $windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=username]", 'leftclick');
    //type your username
    $windowObj->sendKeyPresses("yourUsername");

    //find the password input box, here it has id=passwd
    $windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=passwd]", 'leftclick');
    //type your password
    $windowObj->sendKeyPresses("yourPassword");

    //click on the login button, here it has id=login
    $windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=login]", 'leftclick');

    //i assume this is when you encounter the CAPTCHA image

    //find the CAPTCHA image element, here it has id=captchaImage
    $element    = $windowObj->getElement("[id=captchaImage]");
    $loc        = $element['location'];

    //tell the screenshot to only get the CAPTCHA image
    $windowObj->setRasterSize($loc['top'], $loc['left'], ($loc['right'] - $loc['left']), ($loc['bottom'] - $loc['top']));


    $imageData  = $windowObj->screenshot("png");
    $sessionUID  = uniqid();

    $saveWindowObj = serialize($windowObj);

    //save the window object so we can pick it up again
    file_put_contents("/tmp/" . $sessionUID, $saveWindowObj);
}
//now render the CAPTCHA image to the user as part of a form they can resubmit and make sure to keep the $sessionUId as a hidden variable in the form on the page
```

End of the "Setup" session, php shuts down here.

Start of "Working" session:
We assume the user submits the form and it is a post containing the $sessionUID and the text string for CAPTCHA.

```
if (isset($_POST['sessionUID']) === true && isset($_POST['captchaTxt']) === true) {
$savedWindow = file_get_contents("/tmp/" . $sessionUID);

//delete the saved object
unlink("/tmp/" . $sessionUID);

//bring back the object to life
$windowObj = unserialize($savedWindow);

//make sure the browser is now shutdown on exit
$windowObj->getBrowser()->setKeepalive(false);

//find the CAPTCHA input box, here it has id=captchaInput
$windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=captchaInput]", 'leftclick');
//type the CAPTCHA string
$windowObj->sendKeyPresses($_POST['captchaTxt']);

//click on the button to accept CAPTCHA, here it has id=captchaOK
$windowObj->mouseEventOnElement("[id=captchaOK]", 'leftclick');

//now use the clickElement() etc functions on $windowObj to do what you need to do.

}
```

End of the "Working" session, php shuts down here.